# For which t is the matrix invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

$$\begin{matrix} t&a_2&0&0&\cdots&0\\
0&t&a_3&0&\cdots&0&\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&&\cdots&\vdots\\
0&0&\cdots&&t&a_n\\
a_1&0&\cdots&0&\cdots&t \end{matrix}$$

For what values of t is this matrix invertible? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Develop the determinant along the first column: you get
\begin{align}
&
t\det\,\begin{bmatrix}
t&a_3&\cdots&0&\\
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&\cdots&t&a_n\\
0&\cdots&\cdots&t \end{bmatrix}
+(-1)^{n+1}a_1\det\,
\begin{bmatrix}
a_2&0&\cdots&0\\
t&a_3&\cdots&0&\\
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&\cdots&t&a_n\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

For all real non-zero values I would think because as long as you can reduce the matrix down to I it has an inverse matrix.

Comment: Maybe you missed the coefficient $a_1$ on the lower left?

Comment: yeah, I did. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

For $$-(t^N)+\prod_{k=1}^Na_k\ne0$$
for N even
and $$t^N+\prod_{k=1}^Na_k\ne0$$
for N odd,
if the matrix is a square matrix, $N\times N$

Comment: This is wrong when $N$ is even (check $N=2$). You can correct it by putting parentheses around "$-t$".

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Yes, right. Thanks

Comment: Oops, my brain's not in gear. I meant (or should have) for _odd_ $N$. Now you can correct by replacing the '$+$' by '$\neq$' and dropping the other one. Sorry about that.