# Matrix invertible for which t?

Tags: matrices

I'm having some problems figuring this out. I've seen the [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562564/for-which-t-is-the-matrix-invertible) with a similar problem but I don't really understand the solution posted there. I figured it's better to post a new question with my specific problem.

That's the matrix I'm talking about and I'm not really sure how to go from there.

$$
        \begin{Bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 2 \\
        \frac{1}{2} & t^2 & t \\
        0 & 1 & 1 \\
        \end{Bmatrix}\in M(3, \mathbb{R})
$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A square matrix is invertible if and only if the determinant is non-zero.  The determinant here is $$1(t^2-t)-0(1/2)+2(1/2)=t^2-t+1$$  In order to see when the matrix is **not** invertible, we set this equal to 0 and solve for $t$, giving us the quadratic equation $t^2-t+1=0$.  Thus, solving this for $t$ gives us $t=\frac{1\pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}$.  Since you're only interested (it seems) in real $t$ values, it follows that your matrix is invertible for every real $t$.

Comment: Solving for $t$ when $\bf t^2 - t + 1 = 0$ (i.e., when the matrix is **not** invertible) ... [otherwise, how do we solve $t^2 - t + 1$?]

Comment: Yes, let me clarify that in the answer.

Comment: Nice work, Hayden! (+ 1)